# What grammar entity is this: a "product number"?

Tags: grammar

What grammar entity is this: a "product number"? How can a noun become an adjective (if it does at all)?

Comment: Please note that English Language & Usage (EL&U) is a question and answer site for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*. Have you looked up any of the many online resources before asking here? For further information about what's expected in a question on our EL&U site, see [Ask]. For your reference, note that our other site [ell.se] offers a wealth of information that's useful for both native speakers and learners. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the noun "device" correctly used as a modifier in the phrase "the device box"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410113/is-the-noun-device-correctly-used-as-a-modifier-in-the-phrase-the-device-box)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Attributive Noun" vs " Compound Noun"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346290/attributive-noun-vs-compound-noun)

Comment: See also [What is the specific rule for attributive nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/469818/26083)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [open compound noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Types_of_compound_nouns). "Product" is not an adjective but a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) to "number", specifying that this is not just a number but one that identifies a product. Some more common examples of this construction are "chicken soup", "train ticket", and "toy soldier".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!  Can any noun be a noun adjunct?

Comment: @ivanavdeyev Theoretically (see Wikipedia's [exceedingly long headline example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct#English)), but not every instance is in common usage. I'm not sure if there are particular rules attached beyond what would "sound weird" to a native speaker.

Comment: It seems the only way to master it to learn real usage examples (I hope this sequence works!) in the environment of native speakers. For example: the company president or the president of the company? Or both?